Can't enable https for my ASP.Net Core project build
I've ran into an issue deploying my service. I am using ASP.NET Core 8.
I want my server to work on Https so I enabled Https redirection in Program.cs using app.UseHttpsRedirection. And in debug it works just as intended and shows

Now listening on: https://localhost:5000

But when I export using a FolderProfile and run app it shows only

Now listening on: http://localhost:5000

Instead of https, the service listens on regular http.
I moved https profile upwards on launchsettings in case it isn't considered default profile but it did not help.

Does this thread useful to you?
